Bloomberg tia python package: Corporate Action Setting (DPDF) Override
I'm using the tia python package to download data via the Bloomberg API blpapi. I have my Corporate Action Settings (DPDF) on the Terminal set to adjust for historical prices but when I'm running the python script I want non-adjusted prices. Is there a way to override the Terminal settings?

Never used it but the parameters on line 318 and following are probably doing what you need. https://github.com/bpsmith/tia/blob/master/tia/bbg/v3api.py#L318C1-L321C61
